# springmvc using json response

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

Apologies if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything concrete as an example.

I have the following controller in springmvc.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "main";
    }

}
```

This means I can then access ${serverTime}, my question is, is there a way I can get this response to be a JSON response, without having to hard code all the JSON conversion code in this controller.  Is there a way I can just put some XML in a config so it will know to convert the response into say...

{ "serverTime" : "12 12 2012" }  (ignore the face this probably isn't in the right date format)

I should mention, the "main" is the name of the view (main.jsp), so I want to keep this working the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your method with `@ResponseBody`.

Then just return your item, `formattedDate`.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "main";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/serverTime", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String serverTime(Locale locale, Model model) {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I did this, but you will notice on the bottom line of my question, this breaks the way my views are returned.  Is it possible to do both?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  Are you able to use AJAX?

Load your view, main, then make the request for the JSON data.

Comment: Yeah my AJAX request basically makes the request to the controller for the page it should go to, which it does, but it should also return a payload of JSON.  Are you suggesting I go to one url for the JSON response and another for the html?  That seems a bit nasty.

Comment: Load your view at the root.  Then your view should make an ajax request for the data at /serverTime.  Updated with an example.

Comment: Ah I see, so I have to use two endpoints, can you think of anyway I could improve my design?  Do you think it's a bad idea to have the controller handle the views?

Comment: also - I don't think that code would even compile with duplicate method names.

Comment: Nope, I think doing that's just fine.  You may be able to clean up some of the handling with something like [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), but it doesn't sound necessary in this case.

And yes, it would not :)
Bad copy-paste.  Changed in the example just for future reference.

Comment: Is there any XML I need to annotate so that the response comes back as JSON rather than just a String? I've included jackson-core-asl in my pom.xml

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?  Or did you still need help with that?  I see you marked it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library for converting Java objects to JSON called gson:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Incidentally, if you're wanting to send an Ajax response rather than refreshing the page, add @ResponseBody to your method declaration:

```
public @ResponseBody String home(Locale locale, Model model) { .. }
```

and return your JSON string (assuming you're not updating your model if this is the case).

Comment: Ah, if you notice the bottom of my question, this looks like it will break my view handling as it returns the view "main", is it possible to do this JSON response and keep handling my views within the controller?

Comment: I think BrandonV has answered this.